# Get value from html input text type textbox as string and pass it to C# hashtable being used in aspx

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

The textbox is defined as html input text type and takes input from the users. This value is needed to pass as key to hashtable defined in aspx.cs file being used in aspx file. But the correct value is not being given and an exception is being thrown. Any help in this regard would be helpful. Thanks

The code is as follows:

```
    <% =Hashtable[document.getElementbyId("Textbox").Value]%>
```

document.getElementbyId("Textbox").Value is not giving the correct output. If it is replaced by a string value acting as key then it works fine. The only problem is getting the string value from textbox.

Answer (score 0):

First include jquery in head section

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
```

Try below code to read textbox value :
First read text box value using

```
var key = $("[id$=Textbox]").val();
```

and see if value is present in texbox  if present use this to read hash value

```
 <% =Hashtable[key]%>
```

Comment: var key is a javascript variable and is not taken by C# hashtable

Comment: Are you able to access C# Hashtable in javascript ?

Comment: I think we cant access C# hashtable directly in javascript so you have toh use other options like webmethod.

Comment: If I give a valid key as string to that hashtable it returns the correct value. The only problem is getting that key from textbox and passing it to the hashtable

Comment: $("[id$=Textbox]").val() in this did u got textbox value ? Can you share some of your code.

Comment: It gives the value in key but it is not being used as hastable key. When I write the following piece of code:     <% =Hashtable[key]%>  It underlines the key and says "The name key does not exist in current context". On the other hand if I write <% =Hashtable["a"]%> then its gives the value against it. [Example: "a" is a key stored in the hastable]

Comment: can you share declaration and initialization of Hashtable or try this : <% =Hashtable["'" + key + "'"]%>

Answer (score 0):

Try this it worked for me :
aspx :

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
       <script>
           function GetHashtable() {
               alert("<% = hashtable[this.test] %>");

            }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtKey" OnTextChanged="txtKey_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>

    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Code behind :

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected int test;
    public Hashtable hashtable = new Hashtable();
    static Hashtable sHashtable = new Hashtable();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            sHashtable[1] = "One";
            sHashtable[2] = "Two";
            sHashtable[13] = "Thirteen";
        }

    }
    protected void txtKey_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        test = Convert.ToInt32("0" + txtKey.Text);
        hashtable = sHashtable;
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "GetHashtable", "GetHashtable();", true);
    }
}
```